# Model inside dynamically compiled ngIf or ngFor not workign

Tags: html, angular

Working on some dynamic html generator. Here I compiled HTML + Angular code using dynamic module compiler. The angular related tag is not able to compiled. So for the `'[(ngModel)]'`, used `[value]`. But for other angular tags not able to get any solutions.

Generated Dynamic HTML with angular is:

```
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="ccmmodule.lastUpdated.value">
<label class="control-label">Last Updated</label>
<input class="form-control" [value]="ccmmodule.lastUpdated.value" 
type="text" readonly>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let item0 of ccmmodule.data">
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 pull-right HIDEAVPLISTSYMBOL" 
style="padding: 0;">
<a 
(click)="showCustomAVPModal(item0.avpList.stringAVP,
"item0.avpList.stringAVP","stringAVP",item0)">
<i class="fa fa-2x fa-list-ul"></i>
<span class="badge badge-warning">{{item0.avpList.stringAVP.length || 
0}}</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Can you explain better ?

Comment: In dynamic component genrator, I passed HTML+Angular code in this case the angular related tags like, *ngIF, *ngFor or ngModel  are not working. For input box ngModel I used [value] property of input box , which is working now. But for other angular tags I failed to get any solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What compiler are you using. 
Whatever be the compiler it should be added with the libraries(scripts) you are using.
*ngIf and *ngFor are angular related and your compiler must know it.
Try to add angular library to your compiler.